# How to access second table relationship using Eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I have 3 models:

```
// Customer

public function invoices() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Invoice');
}

// Invoice

public function payments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Payment');
}

// Payment

public function invoice() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Invoice');
}
```

And in my controller, I want to access all invoices by a customer.

```
Customer::findOrFail($customer_id)->invoices;
```

The code above is working well, but I also wanted to attach all payments for each invoice of a customer.

I tried doing `Customer::findOrFail($customer_id)->invoices->payments;` but it looks like the Customer model looks for the payments method too.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3):

```
$customer = Customer::with(array('invoices','invoices.payments'))->where('customer_id',$customer_id)->get();
```

Comment: This works, so I see that using findOrFail methods only works with the model's own relationship methods only?

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
$customer = Customer::with('invoices.payments')->findOrFail($customer_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$customer = Customer::find($id)->with('invoices.payments')->get();
```

[Eloquent Eager loading doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)